# Change the default folder structure in Azure Function project with Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, directory-structure

I'd like to create a Python project using Azure Functions. When creating, files are allocated into the default layout (as recommended in documentation), so currently my project has the following structure:

```
root
 | - function_1
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - function_2
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - function_N
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - src
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - logic
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - tests
```

The problem is that N might be relatively big (>=10), so in this way the project will become messy very quickly. I'd like the project to be of the following format, with functions being grouped into folders (eg for versioning purpose and just to keep them separately from the code):

```
root
 | - v0
 | | - function_1
 | | | - __init__.py
 | | | - function.json
 | | - function_N
 | | | - __init__.py
 | | | - function.json
 | - v1
 | | - function_1
 | | | - __init__.py
 | | | - function.json
 | | - function_M
 | | | - __init__.py
 | | | - function.json
 | - src
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - logic
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - tests
```

or something close to it, the main aim is to separate functions into separate folders.

However when I'm trying to run a project with such a layout, I get message saying that "*No job functions found*", or "*Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json, local.settings.json in project root.*", if I move host.json to functions folder.

Is there a way to configure project to work with this custom layout, so that functions are discoverable from their grouping directories?

All my functions are HttpTriggers.

I'm using Python3.9.7 and Visual Studio Code Version: 1.63.2 with Azure Functions extension for Visual Studio Code v1.6.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**One of the workaround I did to change the folder structure of the Azure Functions project is:**

***- Created the Azure Functions Project of1 `Http Trigger` and 1 `Queue Trigger` in a separate folder called `QueueTriggerFuncs`.***

[image]

***- When I Published this Azure Functions Project, got the same default folder structure shown in Microsoft documentation.***

[image]

***- I tried to create a folder manually in the `wwwroot` folder but it gave me an error called:***

```cs
409 Conflict: Cannot delete directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed. in Azure kudu
```

***So, While publishing the project I unchecked the `Run from package` setting in Visual Studio Publish Profile:***

[image]

***And then published to Azure Function App.***

***- Going to Kudu Console (CMD) - seen the same folder structure but this time I'm able to create the folders manually without any error.***

[image]

***- Created the new folder as `QueueTriggerFuncs`.***
***- Used this command to move my Queue Trigger Functions to the the specific folder created.***

```
mv FunctionsQ QueueTriggerFuncs
```

its kind of format

```
mv FunctionFolderName DestinationFolderName
```

**And Now this is the modified folder structure as expected:**

[image]

***Where my `QueueTriggerFuncs` Folder contains only specific functions like Queue Trigger related functions.***

Comment: Thanks for reply! Firstly, unfortunately your images are not visible. Secondly, so could you only change folder structure by publishing? Any chance to do it locally?

Comment: Which images are invisible/

Comment: I guess all of them.. I see "enter image description here" 5 times instead of actual images

Comment: @julia, I can see the images. Please refresh your page and recheck once. Or try in a different browser

Comment: Hello @JuliaS., Before Publishing I tried to change the folder structure and published but it was unsuccessful. Also, I tried using Run from the package, if do like that, we cannot create the folders after publishing. So I recommended the above solution to change the folder structure, which was running successfully.

Comment: this answer is more messy than the default Azure Function path tree

Comment: Hello @HAL9000, I have seen that you have asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73376316/16630138) regarding Azure Functions Folder structure. Let's discuss on that question and I'll try to help you based on my knowledge!