# How do you specify a custom 'functions' folder for Azure Functions, in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Microsoft suggests the following folder structure, for an Azure Function project:

```
 <project_root>/
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - my_first_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - my_second_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - shared_code/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 | - tests/
 | | - test_my_second_function.py
 | - .funcignore
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - Dockerfile
```

As frequently happens, I don't agree with Microsoft.

In my opinion all the my_function folders should stay under a common path, **not in the root**.

```
<project_root>/
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - my_functions/
 | | - my_first_function
 | | | - __init__.py
 | | | - function.json
 | | - my_second_function/
 | | | - __init__.py
 | | | - function.json
 | - shared_code/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 | - tests/
 | | - test_my_second_function.py
 | - .funcignore
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - Dockerfile
```

In this way that code (never touched) can be hidden by collapsing the main 'my_functions' folder. Much cleaner in my opinion.

Is there a way to instruct VS Code on the base path where to search for the Azure Functions folders?

I'm trying to specify `"azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "./car/azure_functions"` in `local.settings.json` without too much luck.... VS Code keeps complaining:

***No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public.***

Comment: I understand that all the function related folders should come in common folder (eg, my_functions), instead of the root folder by default.  And another one is that common folder structure should be reflected in the kudu without manually changing the folder structure in kudu. - Is this your ask?

Comment: I'm only asking how to move the functions in a custom folder and still be able to start a local server, instead of receiving the error shown in the question

Comment: It seems to be related to the project architecture . I suggest you creating an issue as new feature on [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs)

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT surely you are right, but there is the possibility to workaround it, with a specific configuration setting. In my previous company we were applying the correct setting and it was working fine, I just forgot how to do it. It would be nice to have a public Q/A regarding this.

Comment: @HAL9000, could you provide the github ticket raised on this@

Answer (score 1):

try to set

"azureFunctions.projectSubpath": "my_functions"

in your .vscode/settings.json file

Comment: no, it dies not work.