# How to build an Azure Functions app (TypeScript) in a subdirectory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a project that contains both Azure Functions (TypeScript/Node) and browser-side code (TypeScript/React).  Because there is a subdirectory for every function, locating the functions in the root of my repository is messy and confusing.  Instead I want a folder struct like this:

```
repository root
    tsconfig.json
    functions
        examplefuncname
            function.json
            index.ts
    shared
        utilities.ts
    browser
        something.tsx
        purejavascript.js
        purejavascript.d.ts
    dist
        functions
            examplefuncname
                index.js
        shared
            utilitites.js
        browser
            something.js
            purejavascript.js
            purejavascript.d.ts
    node_modules
        ...
```

TypeScript code in `functions` and `browser` must be able to work with a shared library `utilities.ts`. Note that tsc is compiling all outputs into a top level `dist` folder.

This setup works fine while running my functions locally.  When I publish it to Azure using `func azure functionapp publish myappname` then it appears to succeed, but there are no functions shown in the portal.  My guess is that the `publish` command is only zipping up the files under functions/, and thus misses dist/.

I tried removing `outDir` from tsconfig.json, so that all .js files are written into the directory that contains their .ts files.  That didn't work because I have some pure JavaScript files with .d.ts files, with which I get errors like `error TS5055: Cannot write file '.../server/protobuf.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.

I tried moving my `dist/` folder under `server/functions`, but that didn't work because `node_modules` was not available, and `node_modules` cannot easily be moved.

The only other thing I could think of is to dynamically build [the folder structure wanted by Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#folder-structure), but that seems like a whole lot of hassle, particularly as the code will need to know whether it is running locally or in App Services in order to work out where files are.

I am deploying using the Azure Functions Core Tools, and use VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the Azure Functions default folder structure as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export,v2-v3-v4-done,v2,v2-log-custom-telemetry,v2-accessing-request-and-response,windows-setting-the-node-version#folder-structure).

Created the Same folder structure as you have given in the description:

[image]

[image]

I observed that the files `purejavascript.d.ts` is not publishing to the root folder.

I have done a workaround for changing the folder structure of Azure Function Project after deployment in the Kudu Site. Here is the SO #[71024448](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71024448) Where I have created two different trigger functions in the same function project.

Each function got its own folder created in the root directory and created the folder manually to move respective functions and files by publishing the project from local IDE without zip package setting and moving the files to my defined folders is successful, but this is not the permanent fix for the Folder structure customization.

One of the Azure Functions User @*Hal9000* requires the customized folder structure for their azure functions project [73376316](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376316/how-do-you-specify-a-custom-functions-folder-for-azure-functions-in-vs-code) and tried to change but was not successful because it is related to project architecture.
I didn't find the GitHub ticket where he raised about customization of Azure Functions default folder structure and raise a new ticket on the GitHub Official [Page](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues) of Azure Functions Issues.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response.  I do not see where the MS DOC you reference indicates this is not possible, but I agree that I cannot find anything in it to suggest that it is possible. Unfortunately the question you reference relates to Visual Studio, but I am using VS Code (question updated) and I am trying to deploy automatically using the `func` tool.  I don't follow what you are doing, but it looks too complicated to be worthwhile.  I was hoping that I was missing some configuration.

Comment: Actually, whatever the IDE - I have tried publishing the function project with my customized folder structure, this isn't possible and shown me default folder structure in the kudu site as how it is given in that MS Doc like each folder for every function, etc but I made that customization manually by remove run from package setting in configuration. Another User also tried but didn't get any luck.